# How can I link to a .ejs-page from a .html-page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am making a webpage and I have been looking on stackoverflow on how to link to .ejs-files from a .html-file.

People are saying the following

**In index.html:**

```
<li><a href="views/twitter">Twitter</a></li>
```

**In script.js:**

```
app.get('/twitter',function(req,res){
 res.render('twitter', { });
});
```

But it does not work for me. It says "Your file was not found"

However, when i put .ejs behind, like this:

```
<li><a href="views/twitter.ejs">Twitter</a></li>
```

I can access the page, but without css. I understand that I need to create a controller so I can be able to see the css as well, but how? How can I link it so I can view it correctly? It works on localhost, but not when I first click on index.html and then click on twitter.ejs from there. I can't find any tutorials that refers to this problem.

Comment: have you used `app.set('view engine', 'ejs')`  in your main `app.js` file or something you are running

Comment: @Jana Yes, I have done that in my .js file

Comment: then `app.use('/views', express.static('public'))` static file path? something like this

Comment: if you are not set static file path then use `res.render(__dirname+'/views/twitter', { });`

Comment: @Jana Thanks for your reply. Where should I paste the ´res.render´ code? Here is part of the code where I use ´use´ and ´get´: https://imgur.com/a/ml0C4 Like that, I can see the page if I put .ejs behind without the css as mentioned in original post.

Comment: `use` means `configuration`..`get` means `routing`.. refer https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html...

Comment: create a basic `express` app by using this https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Comment: @Jana I think I already did it. Here is my code: jsfiddle.net/drvsa0va/1 And as mentioned, it works perfectly when I run it with localhost, but not when I try to view the twitter.ejs page when I click on the link from index.html. I only arrive at file:///twitter with "Your file was not found" message...

Answer (score 1):

First set your view engine as ejs.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Next, tell express that your ejs files reside inside 'views' folder.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

In order to serve your static files like css,js,images,etc. Place those files in a folder eg: public. Now tell express to serve these static files:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

**In index.html:**

```
<li><a href="/twitter">Twitter</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done exactly what you wrote here and I arrive at ´file:///twitter´ and it says "Your file was not found"...

Comment: My code looks like this right now: http://jsfiddle.net/drvsa0va/1/

Comment: can you provide your folder structure?